# YA time travel book where a family skips forward through time

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel, young-adult

I read this book sometime in 2002/3 at school in Australia. From what I can remember of the plot:

- It's set in the future
- The main character is a female, and I think either her mum or dad works with the government (I'm pretty sure it's her dad though)
- There's a device that allows them to skip or jump through time
- Her dad is wanted by the government because of the device
- The family has to go on the run
- The main character's sister falls in love with someone from another time and they leave her behind (for some reason I'm getting canoe/water association)
- The mother dies (I think of cancer?) and they bury her in another time
- The main character and her dad continue to jump through time to the last days of the Earth

Answer (score 8):

[image: Stuck in Fast Forward by Damien Broderick & Rory Barnes - Book Cover] [image]

Could it be ["**Stuck in Fast Forward**"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?21066) or ["**The Hunger of Time**"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?21066) by Damien Broderick & Rory Barnes?

From a [review](http://eidolon.net/reviews/rev_0009.html) of "Stuck in Fast Forward":

> Convinced that a plague is about to bring about the end of the world,
> **Natalie's dad tries to pack his family into a time machine** that he has built in the garage - a bubble in space-time called a "vacuole"
> that will allow them to skip into the future.

They're forced to leave the sister behind:

> Things go slightly awry when **Nat's kid sister Fiona refuses to go**,
> snatching the family dog Ferdinand and running away at the last
> moment.

On the other side of the portal:

> When the family emerge from the vacuole a few minutes later they find
> that more than a year has passed, and that Fiona is now a harder and
> wiser young woman having lived through the plague.
>
> **Realising that things are not yet safe enough, the family jumps** into the future, stopping to pick up a cute guy along the way, before
> jumping **again and again through time in search of a future they can
> live in**.

"The Hunger Of Time" is basically an expanded edition of the first book. According to the authors it's also significantly darker in tone. Haven't read the first book, so I can't comment on that. But I did spot some (superficial) changes. *The sister's name has been altered from Fiona to Suzanna*. And the dad's moved on from Donald to Hugh!

An extract from "The Hunger Of Time" shortly after Grace (the mom) dies:

> **We could not bear to leave Mom’s body in the multiple landscapes of
> 5445**. Weeping, we carried her into the vacuole and laid her on a foam rubber mattress. After some hours—or it might have been days, so far
> as I could tell in my grief—**Hugh activated the time change** and brought
> her with us through the green flash.

Natalie bumps into Suzanna/Zanna in yet another future timeline:

> Barong and his consort lived in a kind of floating palace in what had
> once been the South Pacific but was now, naturally, the North Pacific.
> **He and Zanna had been married seven years** earlier with all due pomp and ceremony...

Go through a preview the book [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=U7gVCj3QSncC&printsec=frontcover) or [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=yLsU50wn69wC&printsec=frontcover).